# suitable data structure for storing java project information

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I am extracting information from java source code of a project using AST parser. Information includes:class name, methods, their return type and parameters and variables. So which type of data structure will be suitable to store this information, because after storing it i will use it for detecting Design Patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Data structure can help you in efficient storage, retrival, updation and deletion. I don't think that can directly help you to detect design pattern.

Comment: to store all data/metadata of a class you can use a map/multimap.